# Gap between divs

Tags: html, css

I want the div with the id tagline to appear in such a way that there's no gap between the same and the image. How is it made possible?

**Here's the fiddle...**

http://jsfiddle.net/hxsPz/

This didnt work

```
#tagline {
    margin-top:0;
height: 50px;
background-color: aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image needs to be `display:block;` and no margin on the `p`

```
img {display:block;}
p {margin:0;}
```

[Example fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxsPz/13/)

Comment: @user2899508 you still want to use a css rest, have a look at http://html5boilerplate.com or similar solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the margin from the p also :

```
#tagline p { margin-top:0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use Moob's answer which is `block` or use this css3 `flex`. Beware: this is **not** supported in Safari and IE :

```
img{display:flex;}
p { margin-top:0; }
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hxsPz/19/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a css reset, many elements has a defult padding and margin. In your case it was the `p` tag inside of the `#tagline` div that had padding and margin

```
#tagline p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxsPz/4/) (it does not have a css reset, also added a clearfix for your menu)

Comment: there's still a small gap, aint there?

Answer (score 0):

Always use reset styles

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and the img padding is because of the img display attribute set to inline (by default),and the code below will fix this.

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxsPz/20/